# How to Edit cookie value in IE-10/11 and load webpage with that cookie value

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, xss, code-injection

Can anyone help me on how to Edit a cookie value in IE-10/11 and load webpage with that value?

I tried one editor "IE Cookies View" to edit. But there it throws F12 error.
But it works well for IE-8/9

Tried editing cookie from path:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low
And here, I was able to Edit. But while reloading the page, it takes the new cookie value.

Waiting for reply!!
Thank You